# How does self-observation influence performance?

Tags: experimental-psychology, experiment-design, self-control, multi-tasking

Assuming that the performance in performing a motor or mental task can be quantitatively measured (e.g. by measuring its duration, efficiency, and quality of the outcome) I wonder if there have been systematic studies how self-observation influences these parameters.

I guess to study this influence one needs four experimental set-ups to compare to each other:

1. Just ask the test person to perform the task.
2. Ask her to observe herself (to be able to report what went on, afterwards).
3. Ask her to think loud.
4. Ask her to try **not** to observe herself.

My question is: **Is there a canoncial paper in which such an experiment is described?**

If there was a study where the influence of self-observation is measured in a **multi-tasking setting** ("Do this and do that at the same time and observe  yourself while doing it") this would be even greater.